# Assign random value to variables in NuSMV

Tags: nusmv

I have the following code in NuSMV.

```
MODULE main
VAR
   x : 0..5
```

So x is a variable which can take integer values 0,1,2,3,4,5. Next, I initialize it and lay down its transition rules.

```
ASSIGN
    init(x):=1;
    next(x) := case
         y=1 & z=23: 4;
         TRUE: 0..5;
    esac;
```

What above should say is that x is initially 1. Then if y=1 and z=23, x becomes 4 otherwise x can assume any random values from its domain. This 'otherwise' part of the logic is what I am doubtful. Have I coded this correctly? y and z are variables whose codes are not shown here. Assume something for y and z.

Or should I have written:

```
TRUE: {0,1,2,3,4,5};
```

Because I definitely know the above to be correct from page 4 of [this](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/tutorial/v26/tutorial.pdf) document.

But this is infeasible for a very large domain. Suppose x could take any value from 0 to 293.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

The `integer set` `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` can also be written as `0 .. 5`,
as per the following [documentation](http://nusmv.fbk.eu/NuSMV/userman/v26/nusmv.pdf):

> **2.1.6 Set Types**
>
> set types are used to identify expressions representing a set of values.
>   There are four `set` types: `boolean set`,
>   `integer set`, `symbolic set`, `integers-and-symbolic set`. The `set`
>   types can be used in a very limited number of ways. In particular, a
>   variable cannot be of a `set` type. Only `range constant` and `union`
>   operator can be used to create an expression of a `set` type, and only
>   `in`, `case`, `(• ? • : •)` and assignment expressions can have
>   imediate operands of a `set` type.
>
> Every `set` type has a counterpart
>   among other types. In particular,
>
> - the counterpart of a `boolean set` type is `boolean`,
> - the counterpart of a `integer set` type is `integer`,
> - the counterpart of a `symbolic set` type is `symbolic enum`,
> - the counterpart of a `integers-and-symbolic set` type is `integers-and-symbolic enum`.
>
> Some types such as unsigned `word[•]` and `signed word[•]` do not have a
>   `set` type counterpart.

and

> **Range Constant**
>
> A `range constant` specifies a set of consecutive integer
>   numbers. For example, a constant
>   `-1..5` indicates the set of numbers `-1`, `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`.
>   Other examples of `range constant` can be `1..10`, `-10..-10`, `1..300`. The
>   syntactic rule of the `range constant` is the following:
>
> ```
> range_constant
>     :: integer_number .. integer_number
> ```
>
> with an additional constraint that the first integer number must be 
>   less than or equal to the second integer number. The type of a
>   `range constant` is `integer set`.